# Segmentation fault when trying to print data from a file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

EDIT: I have fully fixed my code now. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int n, i , j;
    char **mensagem;
    char leitura[1000];
    FILE *arquivo;

    arquivo = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

    fgets(leitura, 1000, arquivo);

    fclose(arquivo);

    arquivo = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

    n = sqrt(strlen(leitura));

    mensagem = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        mensagem[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            fscanf(arquivo, "%c", &mensagem[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(mensagem[j][i] == '*'){
                printf(" ");
                i = n - 1;
            }
            else {
                printf("%c", mensagem[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    free(mensagem);

    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to decypher messages like Cesar did back in the days :D. I read a coded message from a `.txt` file. I read the entire line then I dynamically allocate an array of arrays.
That way I can print the columns and the message will be printed normally.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int n, i , j;
    char **mensagem;
    char leitura[1000];
    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

    fgets(leitura, 1000, arquivo);

    n = sqrt(strlen(leitura));

    mensagem = (char **)malloc(n * n * sizeof(char));

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            fscanf(arquivo, "%c", &mensagem[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(mensagem[i][j] == '*'){
                printf(" ");
                i = n - 1;
            }
            else {
                printf("%c", mensagem[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    free(mensagem);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the data in the file:

> ```
> AEEUMOLSHMSCGT*AGU2A***L:****T*****A
> ```

And here's the expected output:

> ```
> ALG2: ESTA EH UMA MSG OCULTA
> ```

And here's the logic behind it:

> ```
> A E E U M O
> L S H M S C
> G T * A G U
> 2 A * * * L
> : * * * * T
> * * * * * A
> ```

I do know that the problem is exactly with the call of `printf`, but I'm unsure on how to fix it.

Comment: Think a couple of times about what `mensagem[i][j]` means, and why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm thinking about this for 2 hours now, and I do know it's probably something silly, but I just can't see it...

Comment: OK, baby steps: What's the type of `mensagem[i]`?

Comment: Int?
EDIT: Am I trying to access an int type while mensagem is a pointer...?

Comment: OK, you have declared `char **mensagem;`. You better be able to figure out the type of `mensagem[i]`, or it's back to Beginner's First Steps in C! We have a fine selection of book recommendations in the FAQ, have a look.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually meant char but I wrote int, just couldn't edit the comment again, and I didn't want to delete it.

Comment: But `char` is wrong, too. It's `char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic example of "two stars does not a two-dimensional array make".

mensagem = (char **)malloc(n * n * sizeof(char));

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fscanf(arquivo, "%c", &mensagem[i][j]);
    }
}
```

`mensagem` is a pointer to a block of `n * n` bytes. However, when you do `mensagem[i][j]`, the compiler will read the value of the pointer, add `i`, and then read the pointer at that address. What is that pointer set to? Whatever happens to be at `i * sizeof(char *)` into your allocated memory - probably zero.

You need to do a two-stage allocation, first allocating `n` pointers, then allocating storage for each string of `n` bytes.

Edit: I intentionally haven't written the code to solve your problem, because you will leard much more from writing it yourself...

Comment: Thanks, and I really appreciate it for not writting the code to solve it. I'd have to do 2 mallocs, the one that I already have done, and another one to allocate the "j" index?

Comment: Yes, you need one malloc for the n pointers, and one malloc inside a loop for the n elements in the other direction. Think of it as if you were to draw it up on paper. The pointers themselves are the numbers you'd write to reference each row of characters.

Comment: I actually fixed it, I looked a bit into it through some links and now I could see the concept problem I was having. The only problem now is that it won't print a single thing, but I'm really grateful for you answer, not only did it help me to solve the issue, but also to understand the concept behind it. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDavid: Mind you, the better solution for a *dynamic*, two-dimensional array of ints would still be a *one*-dimensional array, allocated once (with `M * N * sizeof(int)` bytes) and accessed in strides, i.e. as `p[i * N + j]`...

Comment: By the way, after thinking a bit more about it. I had another issue which is after I did fgets(leitura, 1000, arquivo), I didn't fclose(arquivo), and I was trying to fscanf(arquivo, "%c", &mensagem[i][j]), and it was obvious it wouldn't work since I had already reached EOF. so I had to close it and then fscanf(arquivo, "%c", &mensagem[i][j]).

Comment: Just edited and posted the fully working code, thanks a bunch guys!